# Move files on a remote computer fast

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-server

I am working on a Python project and I need to move files between two different drives in a single remote computer, which is a Windows PC.

I can do this by mounting the drives on my local computer, and then do `shutil.move` in Python or call a shell script to simply `mv` files.

However, the problem is that the speed of moving is really slow compared with moving directly on that PC.

Is there any way I can call the remote host to move it or any other way to make the moving as fast as moving directly on that PC?

Comment: You have to login to remove computer and run function directly on that computer.

Comment: on a linux server i'd say via ssh or scp, like described here http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/10/26/python-101-how-to-move-files-between-servers/
paramiko could also work on windows, since it is native python implementation of ssh, but i never tried it

Comment: Honestly, this is not good Python question... You should move it to ServerFault and tag with Windows. Microsoft equipped Windows with remote administration tools, so a lot can be done. But the interface is complex thingy.

Comment: The way you're trying to do it pulls each byte of the file to your system then writes them back across the wire again. What you need to do is to tell the remote system to do it, rather than trying to operate on it yourself. For that you'll be exploring sysadmin territory, not programmer territory. Not sure why this would be ServerFault.... You should look in superuser instead.